# Update to-many association

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Having a many-to-many relationship between users and groups. I would like to know how to update this relationship with SDR. This is what I've tried so far after reading the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource).

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' -d 'http://localhost:8080/rest/users/5' http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users
```

**Expected result**: Add user 5 to group 1.

**Actual result**: 405 Method Not Allowed.

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' -d 'http://localhost:8080/rest/users/5' http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users
```

**Expected result**: Replace all members of group 1 with user 5.

**Actual result**: Works as expected.

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' -d @members.txt http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users
```

Where the file members.txt has:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/users/5
http://localhost:8080/rest/users/6
http://localhost:8080/rest/users/7
```

**Expected result**: Replace all members of group 1 with the users 5, 6 and 7.

**Actual result**: Only last user (in this case 7) gets added.

Could someone provide an example on how to ADD a single URI to an association?. Also if possible, how to add or replace an association with multiple URIs?

Answer (score 3):

After re-reading the documentation, it does indeed say POST should add to the collection.

My experience has been to use PATCH to add to the collection.

To further the answer: You should be able to use PUT CONTENT-TYPE: text/uri-list with a content body having multiple URIs. Each URI is separated by a line break "\n"

Comment: Hi @Brandon. Thanks for your reply, I'll try with PATCH and see how it goes. As for using PUT with multiple URIs, that is exactly what I did in my last test above. The result was that only the last URI gets added to the collection.

Comment: The last test was using a file upload. I believe curl strips out new line characters when using a file. Try using 
`curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' -d "http://localhost:8080/rest/users/5 \n http://localhost:8080/rest/users/6 \n http://localhost:8080/rest/users/7" http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users`

Comment: What if you want to DELETE item from collection?

Comment: @BrandonBrooks was only missing one thing. I also had to do the following:
```curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' -d $'http://localhost:8080/rest/users/6\r\nhttp://localhost:8080/rest/users/7' http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users```
(empty line)
The key was adding the `$'` to start the data and `'` to end the data block, as well as using `\r\n` in between with no spaces.

Comment: @Piotr `curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users/5` . Associated reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679934/why-is-delete-not-supported-on-to-many-association-resources-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: @CopyandPaste thanks for answer, however 5 years passed since my question, I don't use spring since then :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/rest/users/5" http://localhost:8080/rest/groups/1/users
```