# Why is DELETE not supported on to-many-association resources in Spring Data REST?

Tags: rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST. I am trying to unbind a collection association from an entity (item). i.e. - a property of the item is of `List` type. I want to remove all items from that `List`.

To do this, I am using the DELETE method:

```
curl -X DELETE …/categories/54ea0bcf27a2fb1b4641083a/fixedParentCategories
```

This gives me a `405 Method not allowed` error code. But, it works for a single valued association (when it is not of `List` type). The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) clearly lists `DELETE` as a supported method for associations. I'd like to know if there is a way around this. Also, I tried using `PUT` (Content-Type: text/uri-list) with an empty body, and it gives an error about missing request body. Other operations on this association are all working fine - I am able to add items to this collection, etc.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Document
public class Category { 

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Category> fixedParentCategories;
    …
}
```

Comment: The documentation also states that 405 is returned for associations that are non-optional. What does your domain model look like?

Comment: @Document
 @Description("Category")
 public class Category { 
 
  @Description("Fixed parent categories")
  @DBRef(lazy = true)
  private List<Category> fixedParentCategories;
 
 }

Comment: Added the domain object to the original post

Comment: As I was testing this, I also observed this:- a PUT (Content-Type: application/json) on the item (the entity) clears all the associations. I ended up using PATCH so that they retain their value. Is this expected? Of course I read the documentation which says I need to use PATCH when I want only those properties provided in the request body JSON to be updated, and to leave the remaining untouched. But does that hold for the associations too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked the code and you're right, we're actively rejecting `DELETE` requests for `Map`s and collections. The rationale is as follows:

An association that is of `Map` or collection must never be `null` in the domain model. Translating this into HTTP resources means that the resource will always be available and in the worst case return an empty representation (empty JSON array, or empty JSON object). Accepting a `DELETE` request would logically `null` the relationship in the domain model and thus lead to a state that contradicts the very first assumption.

We generally recommend to simply PUT an empty body with media type `text/uri-list` to the association resource to empty out the associations as that's semantically more correct. Consider it like the difference between truncating and dropping a database table.

If you think that should change and have good reasons that you can back your request with, feel free to open a ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST).

Comment: Thank you for having a look at it. Indeed I completely understand the rationale, and hence, I attempted using PUT (Content-Type: text/uri-list) with an empty body, and it gives an error about missing request body. (This was mentioned in my original post itself).

Comment: I've added [test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/8b3b7bac98e155b68ff896aea359f060d0aee797#diff-1be08248c5e5c2b67ff975b9e91e57b9R221) showing that a `PUT` to the item resource does not wipe associations and `PUT`ting an empty `String` to the association resource with media type `text/uri-list` wipes the association.

Comment: Thank you. The test cases are good. But, still when accessed over HTTP I still get the same response:-
 { "cause": null, "message": "Required request body content is missing: " } 
Looks like the issue is in spring-webmvc project code. 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodP‌​rocessor.readWithMessageConverters(). 
Here there is a check for empty payload, and throws this exception. 
Bypassed this issue by sending a 'space' character in the payload. Nevertheless, this is an issue.

Comment: Seems this is related to Spring 4.1 slightly changing the way empty request bodies are handled. I've filed and fixed [DATAREST-485](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-485) for you, feel free to give the snapshots a try.

Comment: Thank you. That should fix the issue. Appreciate your efforts on this project.

Comment: @OliverGierke what about deleting single item from collection? Should we do PUT request with all current items besides one we want to delete? It seems it complicates client implementation. What's the correct approach here?

Comment: @OliverGierke how can i delete from manytomany relation ,look up join table