# Deleting an association over REST in Spring Data REST+HATEOAS

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

**I wish to know how to delete a many-to-many association via a REST call. I am able to create records, and associated them, but do not understand how to delete.**

I have a Spring Boot project where i'm using REST and HATEOAS to by pass Services and Controllers and expose my Repository directly.

I have a User Model/Domain class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Version
private long version = 0;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="optimized-sequence")
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 500)
@Size(max = 500)
private String userName;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
@Size(max = 500)
private String firstName;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
@Size(max = 500)
private String lastName;

@ManyToMany(    fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable( name="user_role",
            joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(  name = "user_id", 
                                        nullable = false
                                    ) 
                        }, 
            inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(   name="role_id", 
                                                nullable=false
                                            ) 
                                }
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);

...Getters/Setters Below...
```

As as you can see, I have a **roles** member that is Many-To-Many association with Role class, of which the code is such:

```
@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="optimized-sequence")
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String description;

...Getters/Setters Below...
```

My **repositories** look like so:

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends 
        JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    List<User> findByUserName(String username);

}
```

RoleRepository

```
public interface RoleRepository 
        extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

}
```

Now, all is well. When I access the project root from a browser, I get the repository index/directory in JSON+HAL format. Wonderful.

(Note I'm remove the http:// part from the test below because StackOverflow is counting it towards my links quota)

I, using WizTools REST Client, HTTP.POST to the Role ( localhost:8080/resttest/roles ) repository and create a new Role. Success, Role ID #4 created.

Then I POST to the User repository to create a User ( localhost:8080/resttest/users ). Success, User ID #7 created.

Then I PUT to the User repository to create an association with the role:

```
PUT localhost:8080/resttest/users/7/roles
Content-type: uri-list
Body: localhost:8080/resttest/roles/4
```

Great! Association made. User 9 is now associated with Role 4.

Now I can't for the life of me figure out how to DELETE this association.

I'm sending an HTTP DELETE instead of PUT with the same command as above.

```
DELETE localhost:8080/resttest/users/7/roles
Content-type: uri-list
Body: localhost:8080/resttest/roles/4
```

I get back: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

```
{
    "timestamp":1424827169981,
    "status":405,
    "error":"Method Not  Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message":"Request method 'POST' not supported"
}
```

Comment: What is the solution to this please!?

Answer (score 9):

Although creating a `PUT` request with remaining elements does the trick, `DELETE` is an accepted command to delete an association resource and is in most cases easier to use.

As for your example, this should work:

```
DELETE localhost:8080/resttest/users/7/roles/4
```

On a separate note, when creating the association, it is expected to have URIs in the payload. You shouldn't need to write the whole URL in the body, this should be enough:

```
PUT localhost:8080/resttest/users/7/roles
Content-type: uri-list
Body: /roles/4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is inconvenient,  since all other requests (put, post, get) relies on links not ID's. To perform a delete code need to be written to extract the id from the object _link.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> DELETE
>
> ...
>
> 405 Method Not Allowed - if the association is non-optional

`PUT` means that you replace the whole `roles` Set. So to remove a single link you `PUT` all remaining links. If you only have a single link and want to remove it you would `PUT` an empty collection:

```
PUT localhost:8080/resttest/users/7/roles
Content-type: uri-list
Body:
```

BTW: You won't send a body with a `DELETE` request. It doesn't make sense.

**EDIT**

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679934/why-is-delete-not-supported-on-to-many-association-resources-in-spring-data-rest) from the developer of Spring HATEOAS.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That explains a lot. I have two follow up questions. In situations where the association maybe numerous, is there a way to just DELETE one instead of PUT a whole set without the one no longer needed? My other question is, what is a non-optional association?

Comment: I cant edit the comment anymore. Just want to clarify. Not saying DELETE one as in it has to be a DELETE http method, it can be any method, as long as it facilitates removing just one association instead of entire set without one you need. Or do I have to make a repository for that bridge table?

Comment: @BKaun You can use `POST` to add a single URI, but there is no convenient way to remove a single URI. Non-optional means that there has to be a value. Usually that's the case when a column is not `nullable`. I guess a collection is semantically always non-optional: It may be empty but it's always there.

Comment: @BKaun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679934/why-is-delete-not-supported-on-to-many-association-resources-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: Thanks so much, zeroflagL. I searched high and low before posting here, and the link you gave I saw as well. Of course since there were no "answers" in that thread, I gave up after reading the comments and finding nothing about deleting (glimpsed his comments, I noticed he was talking about PATCH/PUT and I was chasing DELETE, so I closed it in frustration). Almost every curl example out there shows vanilla adding and deleting and as far as associations go, they only show adding. I became so frustrated that I had to post here. You've been a great help.

Comment: @BKaun same situation. Hypothetically, if I have a collection of 10,000 entities in relation to my domain and the user deletes 1, I have to submit 9,999 URIs. Seems counter intuitive.

Comment: The answer by Oliver Gierke is about removing _all_ the items of the list. To remove one element, `DELETE` is a better command. This might have changed in almost two years, so I remove my downvote.