# How to delete a single element from a collection with spring data REST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Consider a JPA Entity which is owning a collection relation, for example:

```
@Entity
class SomeEntity {
  @OneToMany
  List<SomeOtherEntity> someRelation;
  // ....
}
```

Other examples would be `@ManyToMany` relations. According to the [Spring Data REST Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#_supported_http_methods_3), single new elements can be added to `someRelation` by POSTing the entity URIs to the association URI.

There does not seem to be a way to delete single elements from the collection. Though the documentation mentions DELETE as supported method, it seems to be meant only for single element associations. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28713232/3274851) suggests that DELETE on collection associations is not supported. Note that the context in this question was different: I do not want to remove the whole collection, but a single element.

A possible duplicate of this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711439/deleting-an-association-over-rest-in-spring-data-resthateoas) over a year ago. Unfortunately, where wasn't a feasable solution nor a rationale why deleting from collections should not be possible.

So a second question, in addition to the one in the title, would be: Was deleting from a collection not implemented because nobody cared to do so, or are there good reasons for leaving out this functionality?

Comment: did you try write some code for this reason?

Answer (score -2):

The DELETE should be done to the following URL:

http://myapp.com/people/1234/address/567

Assuming that you want to delete address id 567 from person 1234.